# Installed Ubuntu alongside Ubuntu but there is no GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 64 bits alongside Ubuntu 13.04 32 bits. After booting my computer, I expected the GRUB to choose between them, but there is no GRUB.. what can I do know?

Here you have the status of my HD

[image]

As you can guess, /dev/sda6 is the partition with my second Ubuntu (64 bits). As you can it is like inside of /dev/sda2..that is also strange for me..what should I remove in case I have to remove something?

Answer (score 0):

You can burn a [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) live disc and use it to fix your GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the 2nd option on [this](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) page.

1. Boot with Ubuntu live CD/USB (mean installation media, the picture you gave is the right place)
2. Install boot-repair with the instructions on [this page](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
3. Open boot repair program and use recommended repair. (or manually install grub on the beginning of sda with advanced options)
4. Apply it.

This should fix your GRUB problem